# SciTE for lua compiler issues

Tags: windows, lua, scite

After install **SciTE** IDE for **lua** why Compile,Build and run option are disabled.

[image]

What to do,how to enable those portions

**Note:** Installed *LuaForWindows_v5.1.4-46.exe* on my PC(OS=win-8.1 and 64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

You've opened the `.properties` type of file, for which those actions are not defined.

Try opening some other file, for eg. `.py`, `.lua` or `.c` and check whether they are still disabled. If so, open the language specific `.properties` file and edit the following keys accordingly:

```
command.compile.filepattern=
command.build.filepattern=
command.go.filepattern=
```

Comment: thanks for your effort.Now it's working.Looking for one suggestion,which IDE is best for lua.

Comment: I use scite when in windows, and emacs on other platforms. It is your own choice though, whichever editor/ide you're comfortable in.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Why using different editors on different platforms?  It's more convenient to use SciTE everywhere.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I'll be switching to Emacs soon. Most of my work these days is regarding the emacs' web-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your "lua.properties" file:

```
command.go.*.lua=C:\PathToLua\lua.exe "$(FileNameExt)" $(1) $(2) $(3) $(4)
command.compile.*.lua=C:\PathToLua\luac.exe -s -o "$(FileName).luac" "$(FileNameExt)"
# ===  or if you prefer LuaJIT  ===
#command.go.*.lua=C:\PathToLuaJIT\luajit.exe -eio.stdout:setvbuf'no' "$(FileNameExt)" $(1) $(2) $(3) $(4)
#command.compile.*.lua=C:\PathToLuaJIT\luajit.exe -b "$(FileNameExt)" "$(FileName).luac"

calltip.lua.word.characters=.:$(word.chars.lua)
calltip.lua.end.definition=)
api.$(file.patterns.lua)=$(SciteDefaultHome)\lua5.api;$(SciteDefaultHome)\SciTELua.api
```

Use menu View -> Parameters to set values for $(1)...$(4)

Calltip files you need:

- [lua5.api](http://pastebin.com/k2eSZa4K) (general Lua functions)
- [SciTELua.api](http://pastebin.com/AWc5Eud8) (for accessing SciTE objects)

Comment: thanks for your reply, what to do with those files lua5.api and SciTELua.api .Will i download it and show the path on parameter set value.What to do?

Comment: Just copy them to your SciTE folder (where all .properties files are located)